# Code after a dispatch() isn't being executed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have some code that looks like this:

Reducer:

```
const foo = (bar) => {
  console.log("here");
  return {
    type: "FOO",
    bar
  }
}
```

Inside the render() of a container

```
console.log(1);
console.log(this.props.dispatch);
console.log(foo);
this.props.dispatch(foo(
  {a: 1, b: 2}
));
console.log(2);
```

The output that I see in Chrome is:

```
1
<dispatch function>
<my foo reducer function>
here
```

Note that the `2` is missing.
I don't get any errors, no redirects, no nothing. The code execution just stops after the `dispatch()` call.

Any suggestions how could I debug that or ideas what could the problem be?

Comment: I can't yet say why, but if feels wrong to be calling dispatch right in the middle of the render event.  Usually dispatch happens in response to a UI event from the user.   I couldn't quickly find anything that proves its wrong though - just a thought.

Comment: Now I think about it some more - if you call dispatch, then react is supposed to update the props and re-render.  Maybe you have a hangup there, where it's waiting for the render to complete, but it cant complete because it's waiting...

Comment: @GreenAsJade That was the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record :)

You can't call `dispatch()` in `render()`.

(Because if you do, your props are updated, so a fresh render is called for in the middle of the current one.  That's going to be either a hangup (waiting for yourself) or an infinite recursion.  The evidence says hangup! )

Comment: A possibly-interesting footnote is that if you follow the component/container pattern, you theoretically never would have `dispatch` in `render`, because containers `dispatch` and components `render`.  I haven't been able to actually implement this cleanly, but that is a topic for another day!